# jQuery mobile same page transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a detailview of products and when I'm in this detailview I can swipe left and right to load the next or previous product. I want a swipe-right animation when I load the next and a swipe-left animation when I load the previous item. It loads the next/prev item perfectly but without an animation.

```
 var element = document.getElementById("product_detail_page");
var mc = new Hammer(element);
mc.on("swipeleft", function (ev) {
    var now_index = current_index - 1;
    if (now_index >= 0) {
        current_index--;
        show_product(now_index, true);
    }
});
mc.on("swiperight", function (ev) {
    var now_index = current_index + 1;
    if (now_index >= 0 && now_index < products.length - 1) {
        current_index++;
        show_product(now_index, false);
    }
});


function show_product(index, rev) {
var v = products[index];
$.mobile.changePage($("#product_detail_page"), {transition: 'slide', reverse: rev });
$("#product_detail_headline").text(v.product_title);
$("#product_detail_image").attr("href", v.product_image);
$("#product_detail_image").find("img").attr("src", v.product_image);

$("#product_details_description").html(v.product_description);
$("#product_details_price_text").text(v.product_price + " €");
$("#add_to_merkliste").attr("data-id", v.product_id);

$(".merkliste_button_text").text("Zur Merkliste hinzufügen");
$("#add_to_merkliste").find("i").addClass("zmdi-star-outline").removeClass("zmdi-star").removeClass("yellow");


$.each(merkliste, function (index, value) {
    if (value.product_id == v.product_id) {
        $(".merkliste_button_text").text("Von Merkliste entfernen");
        $("#add_to_merkliste").find("i").addClass("zmdi-star").removeClass("zmdi-star-outline").addClass("yellow");
    }
});

if (localStorage.getItem("show_prices") == "off") {
    $("#product_details_price_wrapper").hide();
} else {
    $("#product_details_price_wrapper").show();
}

if (v.product_price.length < 1) {
    $("#product_details_price_wrapper").hide();
} else {
    $("#product_details_price_wrapper").show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#product_detail_page"), {transition: 'slide', reverse: rev, allowSamePageTransition: true });
```

Reference: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

If you are using jQM 1.4.x, then you should use the pagecontainer widget:

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#product_detail_page", { transition: 'slide', reverse: rev, allowSamePageTransition: true } );
```

Reference: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change